# Why does weaviate not return an error message if data is inserted into a non existant class?

Tags: weaviate

If I noticed that if I attempt to enter data into a class that doesn't exist in weaviate it simply ignores the command and does not return an error message to the client. It even returns a vectorized entry. Is this by design and if yes how can I check if it actually put something in its database?

Comment: Could you clarify with a minimal reproducable code example?

Comment: I solved it. Turns out, if weaving doesn't fina a class, it simply creates it from scratch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upload into a class that does not exist, weaviate will automatically create that class. This feature is called auto schema and is turned on by default. If you turned it off, then weaviate will throw an error if you upload into a class that does not exist. More details in the docs [here](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/configuration/schema-configuration#auto-schema).